# CSS Animations on Hover with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I need a CSS Animation to play forwards once on mouse enter and play in reverse once when mouse leaves a certain div. I have a JsFiddle [here](http://bit.ly/1El11aM).

I need the class=".item" div to be the one that the mouse enter is triggered on.
The 'animation' is actually 4 different animations that each red line has. Each red line is also part of the ".line" css class, so I simply tell all the animations to start by modifying the ".line" class. Thanks

Comment: have you try jQuery animate funtion 
  $(.item).animate({'top': '-=30px'},'slow');
});

Comment: Yeah I would rather not do that because of the difficulty involved with rotating the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use mouseenter and mouseleave with jquery animation.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="divToAnimate">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".divToAnimate").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".divToAnimate").animate({left:'50px'});
  });
  $(".divToAnimate").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".divToAnimate").animate({left:'0px'});
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.container{
    background-color: green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.divToAnimate{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}
```

You can edit css with the animate function, too.

[jquery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)